# Parameter stability in cross sectional data

Tags: cross-validation

Are there established methods to test for parameter stability for cross sectional regression?

For time series regression, I am aware that Kalman filter can be used to detect parameter stability.

I suppose k-fold cross validation and getting MSE's would one indirect way, but wondering if there are alternatives...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of parameter differences your are suspecting that could be in your data.

One possible idea is to check whether there are (unobserved) groups in your data with different sets of parameters. Then you could use model-based clustering also known as finite mixture models or latent class regression. Given a number k of clusters/groups this fits k different sets of parameters and associated membership probabilities using the EM algorithm. And a frequently used way to select k is to fit models for k = 1, 2, 3, ... and then use some information criterion (e.g., BIC) to select the number of clusters.

If you are using R, one package for this is `flexmix` which has been introduced in the following nice papers:  Leisch F (2004). "FlexMix: A general framework for finite mixture models and latent class regression in R". *Journal of Statistical Software*, **11**(8), 1-18. http://www.jstatsoft.org/v11/i08/. Grün B, Leisch F (2008). "FlexMix Version 2: Finite mixtures with concomitant variables and varying and constant parameters". *Journal of Statistical Software*, **28**(4), 1-35. http://www.jstatsoft.org/v28/i04/.

The latter paper also describes how so-called concomitant variables can be included in the model that help to separate your groups/clusters. Another approach employing such concomitant information that can detect parameter instabilities in groups of observations is model-based recursive partitioning. It is in our `partykit` package and was introduced in: Zeileis A, Hothorn T, Hornik K (2008). "Model-Based Recursive Partitioning". *Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics*, **17**(2), 492-514. http://dx.doi.org/10.1198/106186008X319331.

Of course, there are also many other methods that may or may not be suitable for your model/data. There are other clustering algorithms and R packages. And also there are other packages that implement things like varying coefficient models or other flexible regression techniques.